# MariaDb varchar(20)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm new. I want to learn programming.
I am currently using php and mariadb.
I would like to use varchar (20) in a table of the database. Does this really give me 20 characters? Is it the case if I actually only used 10 characters of varchar(20) for test,30,40?
I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Don't be tempted to use TEXT or related data types unless you really really need them. They're much less efficient to store, search, and retrieve than VARCHAR data types. Don't ask how I know this :-)

Answer (score 0):

The length of a `varchar()` column refers to the maximum number of characters that can be stored in the column.

So if you declare a column to be `varchar(20)` you can store up to twenty characters.  Note that a "character" might occupy more than one byte, so the length of the column in bytes could be more than 20.  Or less than 20 if there are fewer characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use less characters in a varchar you don't waste space, on the other side if you say char20, you waste unused space if what you store is smaller.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The number 30 is dynamic and indicates an ID of the record of another database table. The number 40 describes a number of seconds of a time. However, this must not exceed 24h. What length would you suggest?

Comment: @Michael you should not store multiple different data as a delimited list in a column. Store each data point in a separate column.